# How to use getJson method properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest, getjson

Here is my code I am getting error related "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" how to use getJson method properly. Any help would be appreciated

```js
  $.getJSON('//freegeoip.app/json/', function(location) {});
```

Comment: You seem to have a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. What is the actual service you're using? The given URL is redirected to ipbase.com, which seems to need an API key ..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $.getJSON("//freegeoip.app/json/", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
      $("div").append(field + " ");
    });
  });
```